# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException No method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider

Tags: flutter

При запуске, приложение зависает, появляется черный экран и все, больше ничего не происходит.
Запуск через консоль (flutter run --release) выдает ошибку:

```
E/flutter ( 8422): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

E/flutter ( 8422): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156)
E/flutter ( 8422): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8422): #1      getApplicationDocumentsDirectory (package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:139)
E/flutter ( 8422): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8422): #2      main.<anonymous closure> (package:mylibrary/main.dart:26)
E/flutter ( 8422): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8422):
```

---

Версия:

```
Flutter 2.0

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

---

Код:

```
Future<void> main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

   String? applicationDocumentsDirectory;

   await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((value) {
       applicationDocumentsDirectory = value.path;
       print("applicationDocumentsDirectory === $applicationDocumentsDirectory");
   });

  runApp(
    MyApp(
      initArgs: {
        'applicationDocumentsDirectory': applicationDocumentsDirectory,
      },
    ),
  );

}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Object initArgs;

  MyApp({
    required this.initArgs,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map initArgs = this.initArgs as Map;
    final String applicationDocumentsDirectory = initArgs['applicationDocumentsDirectory'];

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', 'US'),
        const Locale('ru', 'RU'),
      ],
      title: "",
      home: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<BottomProvider>(create: (context) => BottomProvider()),
        ],
        child: HomePage(
          applicationDocumentsDirectory: applicationDocumentsDirectory,
          title: "",
        ),
      ),
      routes: {
        '/book_page': (context) => BookPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

В файле pubspec импортированы следующие библиотеки:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+2
  intl: ^0.17.0
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.7.3
```

Если убрать image_picker то приложение запускается как надо.
Я во Flutter-е новичок, думал может быть библиотеки конфликтуют path_provider: ^2.0.1 и image_picker: ^0.7.3 .. Поэтому скопировал полностью пример path_provider и вставил туда все свои зависимости, в первую очередь image_picker, но там пример работает и не зависает. Что я делаю не так? Подскажите пожалуйста))

flutter doctor выдает все окей))

Comment: А если зайти на pub.dev, ввести image_picker, откроется страница библиотеки. Перейти на вкладку Version. ^0.7.3 это последняя версия. Скопировать предпоследнюю версию ^0.7.2. Вставить в свой pubspec. И попробыать со старой версией. Возможно все получится

Comment: Не получается, когда проблему заметил была именно 0.7.2 версия.
Для уверенности еще раз только что попробовал, не помогло

Comment: Интересно то, что в режиме DEBUG все работает исправно

Comment: Я ничего понял)) Но в этой ветке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080990/no-implementation-found-for-method-getapplicationdocumentsdirectory-on-channel-p помогло только сообщение от @Ramees Thattarath

android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
       release {
            ...
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}
Но мне кажется это костыль, хотелось бы разобраться, почему там работает, а у меня нет?)))

Comment: Там еще речь идет, создали ли Вы проект с  с поддержкой kotlin и swift или нет. Многим плагинам нужно, что бы проект был с поддержкой.

Comment: Да, создал. Я, даже пробовал заново создать проект

Comment: Просмотрите еще раз документацию. Там много заморочек. НАпример: API < 29

No configuration required - the plugin should work out of the box.
API 29+

Add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" as an attribute to the <application> tag in AndroidManifest.xml. The attribute is false by default on apps targeting Android Q.

Comment: Это тоже делал - не помогло

Comment: Уважаемый Александр Александров, у меня бывают проблемы с плагинами, потому что не соответствуют версиям SDK Dart в Android Studio и Min Dart SDK на сайте. В моем случае, 2.10.4 в студии, а последние на сайтах 2.12